# TSQL Group By Issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a TSQL query that I am trying to group data on. The table contains records of users and the access keys they hold such as site admin, moderator etc. The PK is on User and access key because a user can exist multiple times with different keys.

I am now trying to display a table of all users and in one column, all of the keys that user holds.

If bob had three separate records for his three separate access keys, result should only have One record for bob with all three of is access levels.

```
  SELECT   A.[FirstName],
                 A.[LastName],
                 A.[ntid],
                 A.[qid],
                 C.FirstName AS addedFirstName,
                 C.LastName AS addedLastName,
                 C.NTID AS addedNTID,
                 CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), p.TIMESTAMP, 101) AS timestamp,
                 (
                    SELECT k.accessKey,
                           k.keyDescription
                    FROM TFS_AdhocKeys AS k
                    WHERE p.accessKey = k.accessKey
                    FOR      XML PATH ('key'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('keys')
                 )
        FROM     TFS_AdhocPermissions AS p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.EmployeeTable as A
        ON p.QID = A.QID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.EmployeeTable AS C
        ON p.addedBy = C.QID
        GROUP BY a.qid
        FOR      XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
    END
```

I am trying to group the data by a.qid but its forcing me to group on every column in the select which will then not be unique so it will contain the duplicates.

Whats another approach to handle this?

Currently:

```
UserID   |   accessKey
123      |   admin
123      |   moderator
```

Desired:

```
UserID   |   accessKey
123      |   admin
             moderator
```

Comment: Every column must either be listed in the GROUP BY, or be collected with an aggregate function, but not both. Note that one of **MIN()** and **MAX()** is often suitable as an aggregate function for *char* and *varchar* fields.

Comment: Correct, pretty much what the error said that I received which I didnt know how to adjust for which is then why I posted a question asking for some additional guidance

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I was working on something and had a similar problem.  Like your query, I had an inner 'for xml' with joins in the outer 'for xml'.  It turned out it worked better if the joins were in the inner 'for xml'.  The code is pasted below.  I hope this helps.

```
Select
(Select Institution.Name, Institution.Id
, (Select Course.Courses_Id, Course.Expires, Course.Name
    From
        (Select Course.Courses_Id, Course.Expires, Courses.Name  
        From Institutions Course Course Join Courses On Course.Courses_Id = Courses.Id
        Where Course.Institutions_Id = 31) As Course
        For Xml Auto, Type, Elements) As Courses
    From Institutions Institution
For Xml Auto, Elements, Root('Institutions') )
```

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have the definitions for the other tables you have I just make a sample test data and you can follow this to answer yours.

**Create statement**

```
CREATE TABLE #test(UserId INT, AccessLevel VARCHAR(20))
```

**Insert sample data**

```
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(123, 'admin') 
                        ,(123, 'moderator')
                        ,(123, 'registered')
                        ,(124, 'moderator')
                        ,(124, 'registered')
                        ,(125, 'admin')
```

By using `ROW_NUMBER()` you can achieve what you need

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY UserId) As Rn
            ,UserId
            ,AccessLevel
    FROM #test
)
SELECT  CASE Rn 
            WHEN 1 THEN UserId
            ELSE NULL
        END AS UserId
        ,AccessLevel
FROM C
```

**Output**

```
UserId  AccessLevel
------  -----------
123     admin
NULL    moderator
NULL    registered
124     moderator
NULL    registered
125     admin
```